# How to stop readtext function adding extra quotes in R?

Tags: r, string, text

I want to read some Word documents into R and extract the sentences that are contained within quotation marks. When I used the `readtext` function from that package it adds extra quotes around the whole string of each article. Is there a way to change this?

```
path <- "folder"
    mydata <-
      readtext(paste0(path, "\\*.docx")) 
    mydata$text

quotes <- vector() 
for (i in c(1:2)){ 
  quotes[i] <- sub('.*?"([^"]+)"', "\\1", mydata$text[i])
}
```

Here's the content of both Word documents:

> A Bengal tiger named India that went missing in the US state of Texas, has been found unharmed and now transferred to one of the animal shelter in Houston.
> "We got him and he is healthy," said Houston Police Department (HPD) Major Offenders Commander Ron Borza.

> A global recovery plan followed and WWF – together with individuals, businesses, communities, governments, and other conservation partners – have worked tirelessly to turn this bold and ambitious conservation goal into reality. “The target catalysed much greater conservation action, which was desperately needed,” says Becci May, senior programme advisor for tigers at WWF-UK.

and this is what my current output looks like

> [1] "We got him and he is healthy, said Houston Police Department (HPD) Major Offenders Commander Ron Borza."

> [2] "A global recovery plan followed and WWF – together with individuals, businesses, communities, governments, and other conservation partners – have worked tirelessly to turn this bold and ambitious conservation goal into reality. “The target catalysed much greater conservation action, which was desperately needed,” says Becci May, senior programme advisor for tigers at WWF-UK."

Comment: Can you show us your output? Without the word document it is impossible to run your code.

Comment: I just noticed that the quotation marks are a different type, straight and curly which adds to the issue!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is related to the different types of quotations marks i.e. curly Vs straight. I can remove them as follows:

```
#' remove curly punctuation 
mydata$text <- gsub("/’", "/'", mydata$text, ignore.case = TRUE)
mydata$text <- gsub("[“”]", "\"", gsub("[‘’]", "'", mydata$text))
```